# Symfony2 - HTML5 required checkbox field message

Tags: html, symfony, checkbox

I'm having a strange behavior when adding a message to the required checkbox field. This is the field definition:

```
$form = $form->add('in_name_of_president', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => $this->trans("Actúo en nombre del presidente"),
                    'mapped' => false,
                                'attr'=>array('oninvalid'=>"setCustomValidity('Convocar junta es una acción reservada al presidente. Debes clicar el cuadro de confirmación')"),
                    'constraints' => new True(array(
                    'message' => "Convocar junta es una acción reservada al presidente. Debes clicar el cuadro de confirmación"
                                ))));
```

If I check the checkbox before submitting the form it works fine, but if I try to submit without checking it, I get the error message, and then, if I check it and try to submit again, I'm still getting the error, although the checkbox is now checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `True` validator. All validator not checks the value, if value is NULL (Expects: `NotNull`, `NotBlank`). (As example: https://github.com/UserScape/symfony-component-bundle/blob/master/Validator/Constraints/TrueValidator.php#L34). And if the checkbox not checked, in form data your have `NULL` value. (For more info, see the source of `CheckboxType` in Symfony Form).

If your want check the checkbox is checked, you must use `NotNull` validation.

Comment: It isn't. I'm getting the same behavior with `NotNull` validation.